# How to expand relative paths in shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script to set environment variables on linux 2.6 using bash.
So the script contains commands like:

```
export SRC_DIR=..
export LIBPATH=${SRC_DIR}/lib
```

the problem is that when i try to do echo $LIBPATH, it shows "../lib" as opposed to expanding the SRC_DIR to full path. I would really like the script to print something like /home/x/lib as opposed to ../lib.

UPDATE
The script should evaluate SRC_DIR to be one directory upwards from the script's location and not the current directory from where the script is invoked

Answer (score 74):

#### Change Directory in Subshell

There's a little trick you can use to get the absolute path from a relative path without changing the present working directory. The trick is to move to the relative path in a subshell, and then expand the working directory. For example:

```
export SRC_DIR=$(cd ..; pwd)
```

#### Relative Paths from Script Instead of Invocation Directory

To change to a relative path from a script's location, rather than the current working directory, you can use a [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or the *dirname* utility. I prefer *dirname*, since it's a little more explicit. Here are both examples.

```
# Using /usr/bin/dirname.
export SRC_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."; pwd)

# Using the "remove matching suffix pattern" parameter expansion.
export SRC_DIR=$(cd "${0%/*}/.."; pwd)
```

Comment: Sorry i spoke early. This has same issue that the script needs to be executed from the folder where it is located. But if i run the above script from /tmp, the SRC_DIR would evaluate to root folder such as /

Comment: @Jimm PEBKAC. If you place your script in /tmp and then provide a relative path of ".." from the script's dirname, then of course you get /. You probably want "../src" or some other similar construction.

Answer (score 19):

The `readlink` command is capable of not only resolving symlinks, but also canonicalizing relative paths. Be careful, since you may not want the behaviour of resolving symlinks in all your scripts. If you don't want to resolve symlinks, `pwd` would be the best; note the use of a subshell, so the cd command does not affect the working directory in the main shell.

```
# The path you want to get information on... (for readability)
your_path=..

# Using /bin/readlink (resolves symlinks)
export SRC_DIR=$(readlink --canonicalize $your_path)

# Using /usr/bin/dirname (keeps symlinks)
export SRC_DIR=$(cd $your_path ; pwd)
```

Answer (score 10):

I usually use

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$(readlink -f ${0%/*})
```

It should return the full path to the script, and even resolves all the links along the way.

Comment: This has same issue where $0 evaluates to word bash. My first line in script is #!/usr/bin/env bash. When i echo $SCRIPT_DIR, it does path expansion, but it also adds the word bash. I am executing the file directly by ./env.sh

Answer (score 9):

Digging up this old thread to add what i've found to work nicely:

export SRC_DIR = `realpath ..`

see more information here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it gets posted over-and-over again while not being a solution, because `realpath` is not part of the POSIX standard and therefore can't be relied upon on every system.

Comment: For most systems it's a better solution 

Comment: However, when `realpath` is available, it's the absoutely simplest and best possible solution.

Comment: @Bachsau Many systems are not POSIX compliant either.

Answer (score 2):

When I do this I use echo like so:

```
export SRC_DIR=`echo $HOME/bin/`
```

Answer (score 1):

With zsh, it's quite simple using the `:P` modifier:

```
export SRC_DIR=..
export LIBPATH=${SRC_DIR:P}/lib
```

https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
export SRC_DIR=`pwd`;
```

**Update:**

Since you want path relative to the script's location on the filesystem, use this instead:

```
export SRC_DIR=`dirname $0`
```

**Update2:**

Your script must be invoked directly and not as `bash /path/to/script.sh` or `source foo.sh`. Add a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), add execute permissions and invoke the script directly.

Comment: The problem in pwd is that it would take the current directory from where you execute scripts. so i could be in /tmp and execute the above script in /home/x/scripts, it would take pwd as /tmp. But i would really like ../ to resolve to relative to script file location. Hence correct answer for ../ should be /home/x/

Comment: Oh if you wanted a path relative to script file location, you should specify that in the question! See updated answer.

Comment: dirname $0 gives error, because $0 evaluates to the word -bash

Comment: Are you invoking the script as `bash /path/to/script.sh`? If so, add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of your script and invoke the script directly as `/path/to/script.sh`

Comment: i am executing as source env.sh, where env.sh contains the variables

Comment: This has different issue, where i need to supply the full path name to the script. Suppose i am in the same directory as the script and execute this command. The echo $LIBPATH would now show as ./lib. is there anyway to force . to expand to full file path?

Comment: YOu get the error with `dirname $0` because you're invoking it as `source foo.sh`. You may want to try what I mentioned in Update2.

Answer (score 0):

For keeping error code:

```
function getPwd() {
    $(cd $1; [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && exit 1 || echo echo $PWD;)
    return $?
}
```

Comment: Please expand your answer: why does it work? What is the notation doing? Is there any documentation to this?

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions here worked for me (for `zsh`). I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

your_path="/Users/usr/Documents/Folder/Another/../../../Documents/SomeFile.dmg"

resolved=$(readlink -f "$your_path")
echo "$resolved"
```

Gives me:

```
/Users/usr/Documents/SomeFile.dmg
```

Note that the path in `$your_path` must exist.