# Zsh Alias | Mac OS - No such file or directory but exists

Tags: macos, zsh, zsh-alias

I'm trying to create an alias to activate any given Venv by typing activate [name of Venv].

What I've done:

```
activate (){
    directory = "~/Programming/path-to-venvs/$1"
    cd $directory
    source "bin/activate"
}
```

When I try to run it, if I do:

```
activate Test
```

I get this error:

```
activate:cd:3: no such file or directory: ~/Programming/path-to-venvs/Test
activate:source:4: no such file or directory: bin/activate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use absolute paths instead of relative paths in your function.

Comment: You can't put spaces around the `=` in an assignment, and `~` doesn't expand when it's in quotes. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out problems like this.

Comment: Check out dynamic named directories in `man zshexpn` to see how to configure the shell to let you define `activate () { cd ~[venv:$1] && source bin/activcate; }`.

Comment: @451 : I don't see any _alias_ definition in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question properly:

Use absolute paths instead of relative paths in your function.

Also you may be interested in reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11621788/12020083).